# How to save the file "main.js" so that it doesn't load data from the file "file_name.json"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

From **main.js** file data with paths to images are to be loaded. Currently this data is loaded from **file_name.json** file.

Saving **file_name.json** file:

```js
{
    "images":
    [
        {"file_name":"https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?fitness","alt":"","href":"#"},
        {"file_name":"https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?yoga","alt":"","href":"#"},
        {"file_name":"https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?workout","alt":"","href":"#"},
        {"file_name":"https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?running","alt":"","href":"#"},
        {"file_name":"https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?girl","alt":"","href":"#"},
        {"file_name":"https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?cat","alt":"","href":"#"}
    ],
    "others":
    [
    ]
}
```

Here is a short piece of code from **main.js** file:

```js
(
    function()
    {
    
        $.getJSON("data/file_name.json").done
        (
            function(data)
            {
            
            <-----remaining code----->
            
            }
        )
        
    }
) ;
```

Here is all the code from JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Krzysiek_35/d8yz6g5r/32/

Instead of getJSON with the done function and the date variable there, you must insert the JSON assigned to the data variable. You probably need to remove getJSON with the done function and assign JSON to the data variable manually.

How to save the file **main.js** so that it doesn't load data from the file **file_name.json**?

I will be very grateful for effective help.

Comment: Copy contents of `file_name.json` then `var mydata =` ` paste here the stuff ` (note the backticks). Then `data = JSON.parse(mydata);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've commented the getJSON function and using the copied contents of `file_name.json` file in `mydata` variable

```
$
(
    function()
    {

        //$.getJSON("data/file_name.json").done
        //(

            var mydata = `{
                "images":
                [
                    {"file_name":"https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?fitness","alt":"","href":"#"},
                    {"file_name":"https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?yoga","alt":"","href":"#"},
                    {"file_name":"https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?workout","alt":"","href":"#"},
                    {"file_name":"https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?running","alt":"","href":"#"},
                    {"file_name":"https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?girl","alt":"","href":"#"},
                    {"file_name":"https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?cat","alt":"","href":"#"}
                ],
                "others":
                [
                ]
            }`;

            var dataobj = JSON.parse(mydata); //convert JSON -> Javascript Object

            (function(data)
            {

            //..hidden unrelated code

            })(dataobj);
            //This function style is known as IIFE - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

        //)
    }
) ;
```

Comment: It can remain there itself

Comment: Updated the fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sanddune/k2yLox6z/ . Note that when adding a new slide you have 2 places to mind (one for image and other one for the "dots" in center of the slider), marked with <!-- ADD HERE MORE SLIDES -->